# How to load events from webservices to fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, events, fullcalendar

I try to load events via webservice into fullcalendar.
I can log every "event" in the iteration and it returns the correct data.
However, in the end, it displays the exact same event, for as many times as there are objects in the return value.

All of them are displayed at the exacte same time with the same properties.
If I try to move one, all of them follow to the next time.

I use fullcalendar v3.

How can you load them into the right place?

```
                        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                        var obj = {};
                        var Entry = [];
                        var Entries = [];
                        var i = 0;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            url: "/Service.asmx/getEntries",
                            dataType: "json", // datatype returned by the webservice

                            success: function (data) {
                                var events = $.map(data.d, function (item, value) {
                                    var event = new Object();

                                    obj = item.split(';');
                                    Entry.start = obj[0];
                                    Entry.end = obj[1];
                                    Entry.project = obj[3];
                                    Entry.subproject = obj[4];
                                    Entry.task = obj[5];
                                    Entry.id = i++;
                                    Entry.title = i;
                                    Entry.remark = i;

                                    console.log(Entry);
                                    Entries.push(Entry);

                                });
                                callback(Entries);

                            }, //end of Success function

                            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert("StatusEvents: " + textStatus);
                                alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                            }

                        }); //end of Ajax Function


                    },
```

This is how it looks like in the view:
[image: this is how it looks like]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I created "Entry" outside of the loop so it added a "reference" (which got updated with every iteration).
Than it ended up allways being the same event over and over again.

```
                events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    var obj = {};
                    var Entries = [];
                    var i = 0;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "/Service.asmx/getEntries",
                        dataType: "json", // datatype returned by the webservice

                        success: function (data) {
                            var events = $.map(data.d, function (item, value) {
                                var event = new Object();
                                var Entry = [];
                                obj = item.split(';');
                                Entry.start = obj[0];
                                Entry.end = obj[1];
                                Entry.project = obj[3];
                                Entry.subproject = obj[4];
                                Entry.task = obj[5];
                                Entry.id = i++;
                                Entry.title = i;
                                Entry.remark = i;

                                console.log(Entry);
                                Entries.push(Entry);

                            });
                            callback(Entries);

                        }, //end of Success function

                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("StatusEvents: " + textStatus);
                            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                        }

                    }); //end of Ajax Function


                },
```